# how to override onBackPressed of a camera activity? i.e android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent

is there any way to override the onBAckPressed() for camera activity  i.e android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.

Let me explain what I m trying to do

I have a button when user clicks that a dialog appears which asks the user to either select picture from gallery or capture image using camera.

so the code is like this

```
case R.id.btn_live:
            Intent liveIntent= new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(liveIntent,RESULT_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            myDialog.dismiss();       
            break;

        case R.id.btn_gallery:  
            Intent galIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           startActivityForResult(galIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);  
           myDialog.dismiss();
            break;
```

now suppose user selects any of the two actions then we start that using intent
like this -

Intent liveIntent= new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

The user enters into an the camera activity , now when the user is using camera , i want to apply some functionality if he presses back button.

so how will i do it?
any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cant override methods in external activities you are calling. However, when a user hits back in an activity that was called using startActivityForResult the response code RESULT_CANCELLED is generally returned (there may be instances where this isn't true). In your onActivityResult method simply check for the RESULT_CANCELLED code and call whatever functionality you need